# How to know the limits when finding the area under a parametric curve?

Tags: calculus, area, parametric, curves

In the last question on this paper (http://qualifications.pearson.com/content/dam/pdf/Advanced%20Extension%20Award/Mathematics/2013/Exam%20materials/Question-paper-Paper-1-June-2014.pdf), part (c), I integrated the correct function, but I put the limits as pi being the upper limit and zero being the lower limit. The markscheme (http://qualifications.pearson.com/content/dam/pdf/Advanced%20Extension%20Award/Mathematics/2013/Exam%20materials/Mark-scheme-Paper-1-June-2014.pdf), however, puts the limits as pi being the lower limit and 0 being the upper limit.

Comment: Is that really the only guide? It's not a very useful guide. I don't know how I would predict that the answer would turn out to be negative then decide to reverse the limits before working the answer out. The guide that I would use is to go ahead and find whatever parametric value corresponds to the lower limit and whatever parametric value corresponds to the upper limit. By that logic, pi should indeed be the upper limit while zero is the lower limit. Since the limits are not as such, then either my logic is wrong or my application is wrong. Please explain.

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't fully read the problem. Ignore my comments (now deleted), and my flawed answer (also deleted). I've posted a new answer, which hopefully answers your question as to why the limits of integration go from $\theta=\pi$ to $\theta=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that I've actually *read* the problem . . .

Let $D_1$ be the region in the first quadrant, bounded by $C$.

The goal in part $(c)$ of the given problem is to find the area of $D_1$.

Let $C_1$ denote the part of the curve $C$ in the first quadrant.

Using the angle $\theta$ (from the diagram) as a parameter, $C_1$ can be parametrized by
\begin{align*}
x &= \sin(\theta) + (\pi-\theta)\cos(\theta)\\[4pt]
y&= 1-\cos(\theta) + (\pi-\theta)\sin(\theta)\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
Since on the curve $C_1$

- $x$ varies from $0$ to $\pi$.

  $y$ is always nonnegative, varying continuously, as a function of $x$.

it follows that the area of $D_1$ can be expressed as
$$
\int_{0}^\pi y\,dx
\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad
$$
where $y$ is the value of the $y$-coordinate on the curve $C_1$ for a given value of $x$.

Switching to parametric form, we get
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\pi} y\,dx &=\int_{\pi}^0 y\,\frac{dx}{d\theta}\,d\theta\\[2pt]
&\qquad\;\;\;\bigl(\text{since}\;x=0\;\,\text{corresponds to}\;\,\theta=\pi\\[0pt]
&\qquad\;\;\;\;\,\text{and}\;x=\pi\;\,\text{corresponds to}\;\,\theta=0\bigr)\\[2pt]
&=\int_{\pi}^0 
\bigl(
1-\cos(\theta) + (\pi-\theta)\sin(\theta)
\bigr)
\bigl(-(\pi-\theta)\sin(\theta)\bigr)\,d\theta\\[6pt]
&=-\int_{\pi}^0 
\bigl(
1-\cos(\theta) + (\pi-\theta)\sin(\theta)
\bigr)
\bigl((\pi-\theta)\sin(\theta)\bigr)\,d\theta\\[6pt]
&=\int_0^\pi 
\bigl(
1-\cos(\theta) + (\pi-\theta)\sin(\theta)
\bigr)
\bigl((\pi-\theta)\sin(\theta)\bigr)\,d\theta\\[6pt]
&\qquad\;\;\;\;\;\vdots\\[6pt]
&=\frac{\pi(\pi^2+\,3)}{6}\\[6pt]
\end{align*}

To recap, as to the question of why the integral initially has $\theta$ going from $\pi$ to $0$, it's simply to match the corresponding values of $x$ which go from $x=0$ to $x=\pi$.

Comment: Brilliant answer, and a brilliant discussion was the one that we had, thank you :)